# Jboss (6.4 EAP) to WebSphere (7.x)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, websphere

I am attempting to make a EJB call from Jboss (6.4 EAP) to WebSphere (7.x).
I have a working example from WebSphere (WAS) to WAS, however, the same location and lookup name returns a name not found exception. I'm currently doing this testing inside of a web application deployed as a WAR into Jboss.

I do not have the EJB defined in a web.xml nor in a jboss-web.xml (I don't believe I need it). The EJB version in WebSphere is 2.1.

```
Properties env = new Properties();
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "corbaloc::example.test.com:11000");
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(env);
Object obj= ctx.lookup("cell/clusters/MyEJBHome12Cluster/MyEJBHome");
```

The above throws a NameNotFoundException:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: cell/clusters/MyEJBHome12Cluster/MyEJBHome -- service jboss.naming.context.java.cell.clusters."MyEJBHome12Cluster"."MyEJBHome"
    at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:104)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:197)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext$DefaultInitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:243)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:183)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:179)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at com.test.ejbClient.getRemoteConnection(ejbClient.java:192)
    at com.test.ejbClient.runIt(ejbClient.java:77)
    at com.test.TestRemoteEJB.doGet(TestRemoteEJB.java:59)
```

I also attempted to use the sun factory: com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtxFactory

```
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtxFactory");
```

That yields somewhat similar results:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0]
    at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.ExceptionMapper.mapException(ExceptionMapper.java:61)
    at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtx.callResolve(CNCtx.java:502)
    at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtx.lookup(CNCtx.java:541)
    at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtx.lookup(CNCtx.java:519)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at com.test.ejbClient.getRemoteConnection(ejbClient.java:192)
    at com.test.ejbClient.runIt(ejbClient.java:77)
    at com.test.TestRemoteEJB.doGet(TestRemoteEJB.java:59)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:854)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0
    at org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFoundHelper.read(NotFoundHelper.java:72)
    at org.omg.CosNaming._NamingContextStub.resolve(_NamingContextStub.java:251)
    at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtx.callResolve(CNCtx.java:488)
```

The above was attempted using the following site:[Reference Link First](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/624831)

I then tried using the IBM client jars, just to see if I can get a call to work. I followed this site: [Reference Link 2](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/201272)

I added 2 jars:

- com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient_8.5.0.jar
- com.ibm.ws.orb_8.5.0.jar

I also added all of the jars that contained the EJB classes and stub classes. I used the factory of com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory. It looks up the EJB fine, but during the PortableRemoteObject.narrow call, it fails with a

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.test._MyEJBHome_Stub cannot be cast to org.omg.CORBA.Object
```

I doubt I would be able to use the WAS jars anyway as I have to run with Java 1.8, which won't work with the client jars I have above, nor do I prefer to use IBM jars inside of JBoss when Jboss should be able to do this.

Comment: You probable know that by default WebSphere iiop listens on 2809, not 11000.   If that isn't the problem, maybe something on this page will be helpful:  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rnam_example_prop3.html

Comment: Correcting my previous comment:  Typically you lookup the InitialContext via the bootstrap port which by default is 2809, not 11000.   If that isn't the problem, maybe something on this page will be helpful:  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rnam_example_prop3.html  This page may also be helpful:  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/rnam_example_prop1.html

Comment: I encounter the same issue. can you tell me how you solved it?

Comment: We did solve it. I added the answer and accepted it. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We did end up finding a solution to this issue. There is a magical set of characters that need to be in the lookup for JBoss. Previously, the provider URL and JNDI were separate. Now, they are all in the lookup String as shown below. Additionally, no other parameters were added to the InitialContext.

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(); // no need to add anything to the context

// A few reminders about the below:
// 1. For multiple hosts, separate with commas, i.e. "corbaname::@<server:port>,:@<server2:port2>"
// 2. If periods are used in the lookup name, they must be escaped, i.e. MyEJBHome-1.0 needs to be MyEJBHome-1\.0
Object obj= ctx.lookup("corbaname::@example.test.com:11000/NameServiceServerRoot#cell/clusters/MyEJBHome12Cluster/MyEJBHome");

// Normal EJB things below
MyEJBHome home = (MyEJBHome) javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow(obj, MyEJBHome.class);
MyEJB myEJB = home.create();
```